# jQuery code affecting my HTML image links?

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var goTo = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$('a[name="'+goTo+'"]').offset().top
    },1775);

    window.location.hash = "#"+goTo;

});
```

I have this function in my code to achieve a scrolling effect on my page, however I think it is affecting my image links. When I click on an image it doesn't link anywhere. I'm fairly certain the error is somewhere here but need some help finding it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure there is a hash `#` in the href first before changing anything so normal links will still work.

One way is check `hash` property of the element

```
if(this.hash){
  e.preventDefault();
  // rest of code shown 
}
```

Can also use attribute selector to filter out only links with `#` in href

```
 $('body a[href^=#]').click...
```

Last one assumes all hash links are relative and href starts with `#`