# javascript - display:block onclick function won't work

Tags: javascript, function, menu, onclick

For some reason my onclick function won't display the menu, here's my code:

```js
function showmenu(){
 document.getElementById("mobile-menu").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#mobile-menu{
 background:red;
 height:160px;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div onclick="showmenu()" id="nav-toggle">MENU</div></a>

<div id="mobile-menu">
   <ul>
    <a href="#"><li><p>ABOUT</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>WORK</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>SERVICES</p></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><p>CONTACT</p></li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly even within the snippets on this page. Are you sure that there are no other errors preventing your function to work (press F12 and refresh the page)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635989/jquery-code-affecting-my-html-image-links. I also have this function in my javascript file (wouldn't let me edit into the original post) Once I delete this function the menu onclick works..

Comment: `<a><div>...</div></a>` is not valid HTML change to `<a href="#" onclick="showmenu(); return false" id="nav-toggle">MENU</a>` if you must have it inline